# PHP not rendering in html email

Tags: php, html, email

I cant figure out why some php wont render correctly in an HTMl email I am trying to build.
CODE (Most of the html elements have been removed):

```
$messaget = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Loan Information</title>
<style type=text/css>
table {border: 0px solid white}
#top {width:590px; margin-left:5px;}
#foot {width:540px; margin-left:10px;}

#left {width:560px; margin-left:20px;}
h1 {margin-left:0px; }
body,td,th {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
td, tr {border: 0}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Thank you, $custfirst $custlast
    <br/>Customer Id: $custid,</p>

    <h3>What we have:</h3>

    <strong>What We Still Need: </strong><br/>
foreach ($needed as &$value) {
    $value<br/>
}'



</body>
</html>
```

The first variables, Thank you, $custfirst $custlast, is working.
When I send the email, I see "Thank you, John Smith"

But

```
foreach ($needed as &$value) {
        $value<br/>
    }
```

does not execute php, instead is literately shows 
"foreach ($needed as &$value) {
        $value
    }"
Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP in an email that was sent?

Comment: You can look the handlebar templates by resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use logic calls in a string. You need to prepare the string in a variable and insert that instead. Ex:

```
$string = '';
foreach ($needed as &$value) {
    $string .= $value.'<br>';
}
```

And then in your string

```
$message = "... $string ...";
```

Comment: Oh wow. Duh. Even tho I didnt realize you cant use logic calls in a string, I should have thought to try this anyways! Thank you

Comment: This answer seems the most concise.

Answer (score 0):

Append strings to your variable instead of using a logic call in a string.

```
<?php
  $messaget = null;
  $messaget .= '<html><head>...';
  foreach ($needed as &$value) {
      $messaget .= $value.'<br>';
  }
  $messaget .= '...</body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: Why make this another $messaget instead of answer above?

Comment: I just follow the way you did it. It's all about the code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file my_html.php with:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Loan Information</title>
<style type=text/css>
table {border: 0px solid white}
#top {width:590px; margin-left:5px;}
#foot {width:540px; margin-left:10px;}

#left {width:560px; margin-left:20px;}
h1 {margin-left:0px; }
body,td,th {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
td, tr {border: 0}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Thank you, $custfirst $custlast
    <br/>Customer Id: $custid,</p>

    <h3>What we have:</h3>

    <strong>What We Still Need: </strong><br/>
<?php foreach ($needed as &$value): ?>
   echo $value . '<br/>';
<?php endforeach; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And in other file include this file my_html.php.

I hope help you.